# How to create pdf export of a part of the current page on the client side

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, jspdf, export-to-pdf

I try to understand if I could use PhantomJS (or any similar js library) in my web application (in a javascript function called when "ExportToPdf button is hit) to create pdf export of a part of the user's current page, for example the contents of a div, but with its current styles.
And I need it to be made on client side.

I see over my searches that phantomJS is used as a tool (console app executable), but could I utilize it the way I need it?

Maybe in combination with jsPDF or some similar js library...

Or if you have any other solution to suggest... I already have tried jsPDF alone and it does not get any styles at all (all bootstrap class elements are missing). Also I tried html2canvas+jsPDF to get image of the desired div contents and put it on a pdf doc, but this does not seem to get all the height of the div (only the part that is viewable in browser gets exported)

Comment: Have you read [Generating PDFs from HTML and PhantomJS](http://culttt.com/2015/10/26/generating-pdfs-from-html-and-phantomjs/)?

Comment: Yes I had a look over it in the past, but it seems to be php specific... could it be used without php?

Comment: I thought only the example was written in PHP, with Laravel, not that either was required.  I didn't look further because we decided to go with server-side generation of our PDFs — we output XML and process it with XSL-FO stylesheets using Apache FOP.